# Greedy algorithm correctness

Tags: greedy, correctness

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> CEO is checking on it's employees at a constant times every day (for
>   an example the number of minutes after a shift started> {5, 35,
>   120..}). Calculate when should employees work, so that every time the CEO checks on them they are working. Their work takes 3 minutes to
>   complete and it increases by another 3 minutes every time they start
>   working again (First time it takes 3 minutes, second time it takes 6
>   minutes, third time it takes 9 minutes..).

This is my algorithm in pseudocode:

```
int time = 2
for: every CEOcheckTime in 0 to CEOcheckTime.length
    add (CEOcheckTimes-time) to results
    time = time + 2
```

Ignoring the edge case, where the CEO checks on employees sooner that they can finish the work, is my algorithm correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the 'edge case' this seems fine except your time is being incremented by 2 rather than 3 as per the spec.

```
 int time = 3
 for: every CEOcheckTime in CEOcheckTimes
     add (CEOcheckTimes-time) to results
     time = time + 3
```

a similar just in time approach could be used here that would account for your edge case too.

```
for: every CEOcheckTime in CEOcheckTimes
    if exists(time):
        if last(results) + time < CEOcheckTime:
            add (CEOcheckTimes) to results
            time = time + 3
    else:
         add (CEOcheckTimes) to results
         time = 3
```

edit: i have assumed that if work starts / ends at the same time as a check that this counts as working.

Comment: Thanks. I incremented it by 2 because of I don't know either if it counts as working if checking is at the same time as works end.

Comment: in which case you should still increment by 3 but start at  time = 2.